# Fitness Function - What to do, if value of one Chromosome features is much higher than other ones

Tags: scalability, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a Fitness Function for my Genetic Algorithm. I have got three features (F1,F2,F3 - All are numeric variables), which are taken into consideration for rating the chromosome. If all of them are equally important I can write such equation:
[image: formula]

If their importance would be different, I can multiply features by different constants.
It will all work, if values of all three features would have the same interval. 
But what if F1 and F2 could have a value from (0,10) and F3  for example(0,49)?
How could I approximately scale it? Or should I approach it differently?

Comment: Scale all values to [0..1] (here you take into account if you want it to scale linear or exponentially etc.) multiply with a 'weight' and divide by the sum of weights. E.g: `(F1*4 + F2*1 + F3*2) / (4+1+2)` --> [0..1]

Comment: But weights are constant. So If F1=1, F2=1,F3=30, with proper weights all features would be important. If we will use the same weights for F1=1,F2=1, F3=1 then F3 would be disproportionately less important. (Or am I getting something wrong with your answer?)

Comment: If F1=1, F2=1, F3=30, then F3 is a lot more important (30) than F1 (1) and F2 (1). If you assign every F the same weight, the final result will be the same if any F changes by a specific amount. If you assign F3 a much higher weight than the others, the result will change much more if F3 changes. *edit:* Are you mixing up scale and weight? Because you need to scale those values **before** you weight them.

Comment: Disregard the first sentence in my previous comment, I'll post some example code instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Scale all your values to `[0..1]`
2. Assign a weight / importance to every value
3. Multiply every scaled value with its weight
4. Divide the sum of all values from step 3 by the sum of all weights

I don't know which language you are using, so here is some C# code:

## Feature Class

```cs
public class Feature
{
    public double Importance { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public double LowValue { get; set; }
    public double HighValue { get; set; }

    public double ScaledValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Make sure value is within bounds
            double intermediate = Math.Max(Math.Min(LowValue, HighValue), 
                Math.Min(Math.Max(LowValue, HighValue), Value));

            // Scale from 0 to 1 within defined bounds
            double scaledValue = (intermediate - LowValue)/(HighValue - LowValue);
            return scaledValue;
        }
    }
}
```

## Example Calculation

```cs
// low importance (1), values from [20..-10] (less is better)
var f1 = new Feature
{
    Importance = 1,
    Value = 0,
    LowValue = 20,
    HighValue = -10
};

// low importance (1), values from [0..10] (more is better)
var f2 = new Feature
{
    Importance = 1,
    Value = 1,
    LowValue = 0,
    HighValue = 10
};

// high importance (5), values from [0..49]
var f3 = new Feature
{
    Importance = 5,
    Value = 25,
    LowValue = 0,
    HighValue = 49
};

var features = new[] {f1, f2, f3};
var score = features.Sum(f => f.ScaledValue*f.Importance)/features.Sum(f => f.Importance);
Debug.WriteLine(score);
```